# Fresh Install Ubuntu18.04

Tags: upgrade, python

Hey guys sorry to bother y'all but this will be a quick and easy answer for all you linux guru's out there. I just did a fresh install and upgrade of ubuntu and noticed that python3, python3.6, python3.7, and python3.8 were included, as well as python2.7. Has it always been like that or is the py3.7, 3.8 newer additions. Also since pytohn2.7 is not supported any more do I even need it?

Comment: It's never been like that. Your install is suspect.

Comment: That's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I has never been like that - usually only one Python version is preinstalled, or maybe one Python 2 and one Python 3 version.

Have you activated `deadsnakes ppa` by any chance? There you'd get all these mentioned versions - and Python 3.9, too.

I would strongly discourage you from deinstalling Python versions you seemingly do not need, as the Ubuntu Os could rely on them, e.g. you terminal, the apt command and many more need Python to work properly.

Comment: Nope. No deadsnakes. But python 2 is over so they're probably shipping it with all versions of python 3 and 2 as well for backwards compatibility, I think. I installed and upgraded after python 2 officially ended.